# How to Show result after uploaded file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ffmpeg, dropzone.js

I have a script that uploads the video to a server, everything is correct but there is a problem, after the upload of the video to the server is completed
it shows all the uploaded files in the (uploads) folder as array!

I only want the result of the file I just uploaded, and it doesn't show me the previous files!
I need ffmpeg to improve video quality

index.php

```
<?php
//index.php

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Personal Video Uploader</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 </head>
 <body class="bg-body">
  <div class="container">

   <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone font" id="dropzoneFrom">

   </form>
   
    
   </form>
   <br />

   <div id="preview"></div>

   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 Dropzone.options.dropzoneFrom = {
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  timeout: 300000,
  acceptedFiles:"video/*",
  init: function(){
   var submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-all');
   myDropzone = this;
   submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myDropzone.processQueue();
   });
   this.on("complete", function(){
    if(this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0)
    {
     var _this = this;
     _this.removeAllFiles();
    }
    list_image();
   });
  },
 };

 list_image();

 function list_image()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"upload.php",
   success:function(data){
    $("#preview").html(data);
   }
  });
 }

 $(document).on('click', '.remove_image', function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
   url:"upload.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{name:name},
   success:function(data)
   {
    list_image();
   }
  })
 });
 
});
</script>
```

upload.php

```
    <?php

//upload.php

$folder_name = 'upload/';
$tumb_name = 'thumb/';
$imageext = '.png';

if(!empty($_FILES))
{

 $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $location = $folder_name . $_FILES['file']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $location);
 $upload = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $uploadStr = str_replace(" ", "\ ",$upload);
 $locationStr = str_replace(" ","\ ",$location);
 $cmd  = "ffmpeg -y -i {$locationStr} -ss 00:00:15 -vframes 1 thumb/{$uploadStr}.png 2>&1";
 echo shell_exec($cmd);
}

if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
 $filename = $folder_name.$_POST["name"];
 $imagename = $thumb_name.$_POST["name"].$imageext;
 unlink($filename);
 unlink($imagename);
}

$result = array();

$files = scandir('upload');

$output = '<div class="row">';

if(false !== $files)
{
 foreach($files as $file)
 {
  if('.' !=  $file && '..' != $file)
  {
   $output .= '
   <a href="/view.php?file='.$file.'" target="_blank"> <img src="thumb/'.$file.'.png" class="img-thumbnail" width="246px" height="138px" style="height:138px;" /></a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link remove_image" id="'.$file.'">Remove</button>
   ';
  }
 }
}
$output .= '</div>';
echo $output;

?>
```

**EDIT:**
I put the example on an Array, I don't want it, I just want it to show the downloaded video I just uploaded as a result.

**EDIT 2 :**
There are some who say type $location and it displays the downloaded file, but this does not work!!!
I just tried more than once and with several uses, there is no display where the text is empty

This is an example of that

```
<?php

//upload.php

$folder_name = 'upload/';
$tumb_name = 'thumb/';
$imageext = '.png';

if(!empty($_FILES))
{

 $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $location = $folder_name . $_FILES['file']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $location);
 $upload = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $uploadStr = str_replace(" ", "\ ",$upload);
 $locationStr = str_replace(" ","\ ",$location);
 $cmd  = "ffmpeg -y -i {$locationStr} -ss 00:00:15 -vframes 1 thumb/{$uploadStr}.png 2>&1";
 echo shell_exec($cmd);
}

if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
 $filename = $folder_name.$_POST["name"];
 $imagename = $thumb_name.$_POST["name"].$imageext;
 unlink($filename);
 unlink($imagename);
}


$output .= 'Successfly file is "'.$location.'"';
echo $output;

?>
```

**Result** : Successfly file is ""
no name file :(

**EDIT 3 :**

this code upload.php
functions not working

```
<?php

//upload.php

$folder_name = 'upload/';
$tumb_name = 'thumb/';
$imageext = '.png';

if(!empty($_FILES))
{

 $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $location = $folder_name . $_FILES['file']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $location);
 $upload = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $uploadStr = str_replace(" ", "\ ",$upload);
 $locationStr = str_replace(" ","\ ",$location);
 $cmd  = "ffmpeg -y -i {$locationStr} -ss 00:00:15 -vframes 1 thumb/{$uploadStr}.png 2>&1";
 echo shell_exec($cmd);
}


echo "The file " . $location . " has been uploaded";
// not working
echo "<br>";
echo "The file " . $upload . " has been uploaded";
// not working
echo "<br>";
echo "The file " . $uploadStr . " has been uploaded";
// not working
echo "<br>";
echo "The file " . $locationStr . " has been uploaded";
// not working

?>
```

[image: Result upload.php in EDIT 3]

this error:
[23-Apr-2022 12:31:56 Asia/Riyadh] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: location in /home/prdix/public_html/test/upload.php on line 38

line 38: echo $location;

**About the developer solution Markus AO**

I did the experiment and it is quite good, but dropzone is still missing, because I will upload a large video and the normal upload compresses the video before uploading, here is a picture from my mobile while uploading, but this does not happen with dropzone
[image]

I want to implement this in dropzone as well, because this library does not compress the video, but upload it in full size.

Thank you bro.

Comment: Well if you do `$files = scandir('upload');` for sure you will get them all. You don't need to scandir, why not simply use `$location`, the path of your uploaded file.

Comment: How does this work?  I put it but for the result, you can try

Comment: _I put it but for the result, you can try_ -- I have no idea what that means. Instead of your scandir and loop, just use your `$location` or whatever other variables _from when you handle the upload_ for your output.

Comment: I tried to print $location directly from if(!empty($_FILES)), but to no avail, there is no data, I did not add it in the place of the loop, I just called it from if(!empty($_FILES))

Comment: How can there be "no data" (means what exactly, what errors if any), since you have the variables defined right there where you handle the upload?

Comment: I’m used “echo $location” in at the bottom of upload.php, But he print the same thing!  Nothing appears after downloading but a phrase, not the file path.

Comment: you can check Edit2 example in my question

Comment: Add `echo $location;` inside your `if(!empty($_FILES))` condition, and it will definitely output the `$location` with a value _when you upload a file_. Otherwise none of your code would work. The `echo` in your edit would not have the variable defined if you _didn't upload but just loaded the page_.  In other notes, _is your error reporting turned on?_

Comment: Nothing happened!  It did not write anything to me after downloading, you can try it, the problem is really confusing and it does not print any function

Comment: You can test code in your server !

Comment: _Uploading_ or _Downloading_. Be clear please. There is no downloading happening in your code. `$location` is defined when you upload. If you need further help, **1.** Confirm the status of your error reporting, is it on and set to display all errors? **2.** Add the following _inside your `if(!empty($_FILES)) { ... }` condition_: `var_dump(get_defined_vars());`.. Then upload a file and add the complete dump to your post so we know your actual data.

Comment: Bro :( Perhaps the phrase was not clear, I will tell you that after uploading, the file path is not displayed! There is a strange thing, because I tried several methods in all the ways that I explained, but $location or any functions does not display anything after uploading the file to the server.

Comment: But please, try the above code index.php and upload.php and you will notice that $location, $upload, and all functions does not appear after uploading

Comment: updating my post [edit 3]

Comment: this project in github you can see https://github.com/AjayACST/PHP-Video-Uploader

Comment: When I make a quick MCVE with your code, using a regular upload form, it works exactly as expected. https://bitbucket.org/cmswares/stack_overflow/src/master/mcve/users/so-upload-71955097.php ... your issue seems to be that your javascript is calling `list_image();` **twice**, the second call _outside upload context_, in which case _no variables will be defined_. If you had done what I asked you to do earlier, ie. _placing the debug dump call inside your upload condition_, you would have noticed that it's not run at all, because the file was called with no upload data.

Comment: Thank you brother, you have seen your solution, but I stopped the second call to the list image and I do not need it, it is in the original project, but I removed it and satisfied with the first to display the result of the upload, but the problem remains, I will try the code that I solved.

Comment: I need ffmpeg, but by stopping it in the file, is that harmful?  Or do I remove the tags // and run the file normally and call the list image one time?

Comment: Hello brother, I tried it, I couldn't, is it possible for you to fix it and make it normal?  After uploading the video, a message appears with the file name and path, no problem if you restructure index.php or upload.php, the most important thing is that it works

Comment: I updated the post About the developer solution Markus AO.

Comment: Glad you're getting it sorted. Remember to _view debug data in the right places (as I have been indicating)_. If you have another, separate question about video compression and/or ffmpeg, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: Thank you bro, i tried but how can use dropzone js with ffmpeg in php, and view messeges upload complete?  Did I open a new question?

Comment: My new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71982633/upload-video-in-php-without-compress

Comment: Bro @MarkusAO You can add dropzone or ffmpeg please :(