# Undefined variable PHP uploader video

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, ffmpeg, dropzone

I have a problem!
I found a code to upload a high quality video on my server

using: ffmpeg, dropzone, php

But it has a big problem!

I want after the video upload to the server is completed, a phrase appears with the file name and path
But it does not do this work, and in the report it appears that Undefined variable
this:

```
[23-Apr-2022 12:46:46 Asia/Riyadh] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: location in /home/userme134/public_html/SUP/test8/upload.php on line 21
[23-Apr-2022 12:48:17 Asia/Riyadh] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: location in /home/userme134/public_html/SUP/test8/upload.php on line 21
[23-Apr-2022 12:51:39 Asia/Riyadh] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: location in /home/userme134/public_html/SUP/test8/upload.php on line 21
[23-Apr-2022 12:52:12 Asia/Riyadh] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: location in /home/userme134/public_html/SUP/test8/upload.php on line 21
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Video Uploader</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 </head>
 <body class="bg-body">
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h3 align="center" class="font">Video Uploader</h3>
   <br />
   
   <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone font" id="dropzoneFrom">

   </form>
   
    
   </form>
   <br />
   <br />
   <div id="preview"></div>
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 Dropzone.options.dropzoneFrom = {
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  timeout: 300000,
  acceptedFiles:"video/*",
  init: function(){

   this.on("complete", function(){
    if(this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0)
    {
     var _this = this;
     _this.removeAllFiles();
    }
    viewResult();
   });
  },
 };

 function viewResult()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"upload.php",
   success:function(data){
    $("#preview").html(data);
   }
  });
 }

 $(document).on('click', '.remove_image', function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
   url:"upload.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{name:name},
   success:function(data)
   {
    list_image();
   }
  })
 });
 
});
</script>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

//upload.php

$folder_name = 'upload/';

if(!empty($_FILES))
{

 $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $location = $folder_name . $_FILES['file']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $location);
 $upload = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $uploadStr = str_replace(" ", "\ ",$upload);
 $locationStr = str_replace(" ","\ ",$location);
 $cmd  = "ffmpeg -y -i {$locationStr} -ss 00:00:15 -vframes 1 thumb/{$uploadStr}.png 2>&1";
 echo shell_exec($cmd);
}

echo "Successfly Uploaded File is : ";
echo $location;

?>
```

[image]

I hope you can help me because I am tired of many useless attempts.

Comment: I don't see where you actually upload any files? And if you don't actually upload the files anywhere, then `if(!empty($_FILES))` won't evaluate as true, resulting in your PHP ending in `echo $location;` where `$location` was never defined (since it's only defined if there were files sent)

Comment: What do I do to make it right, can you help me debug the code and make it if a video is uploaded, its path appears in a message to the user? Please

Comment: To see debugging that has already happened, and more code context, see OP's previous question at [How to Show result after uploaded file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71955097/how-to-show-result-after-uploaded-file-in-php). @i0x4r like I said in comments to the other questions several times, **your `echo $location` must be inside `if(!empty($_FILES))`**, and your error is caused by calls to the script with no upload -- and no `$_FILES` defined -- and consequently no `$location` variable defined.

Comment: Markus AO, Yes you solved the issue in a great way, but I want it to apply to dropzone.js and I mentioned that to you in my previous post.